# webscraping returned a list, i need to split it into different lists by type of info

Tags: python, list, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I scraped a website using python for Londons MPs, but the scrape returned information i would need in another list. My problem is that it is "split into blocks" and i have no idea how i could sort these into 3 different lists so they stay in in the real relevance to each other.
I need to put these into a data frame to work with them later on.
I know this is probably a pretty easy question, but i am a noob and quite lost

[my list came out looking like this, i would need name/Constituency/party split into 3 list/columns of a df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Dgb.png)

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the code you're working on

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're scraping https://www.londoncouncils.gov.uk/who-runs-london/general-election/2019/london-mps-elected-2019

This site returns plain HTML with no Javascript in play (as far as I can tell).

You need to find the p tags under div with class 'field field-type-text-with-summary'

The MP data are grouped/separated by a p with empty text.

Thus it is easy to build a list of lists where the sub-lists are comprised of: MP name, Constituency, Party and Contact.

This code builds that list of lists then shows how you can isolate the parts you need.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

with requests.Session() as session:
    (r := session.get('https://www.londoncouncils.gov.uk/who-runs-london/general-election/2019/london-mps-elected-2019')).raise_for_status()
    data = []
    mp = []
    for p in BS(r.text, 'lxml').find('div', class_='field field-type-text-with-summary').find_all('p'):
        t = p.text.strip()
        if not t:
            if mp:
                data.append(mp)
                mp = []
        else:
            mp.append(t.replace('\xa0', ' '))
    if mp:
        data.append(mp)


    print(mp[0] for mp in data) # all MP names
    print(mp[1] for mp in data) # all constituencies
```